# querystring in javascript with browser's back button

Tags: query-string

Consider the following situation:

I start on some page with a URL of `page1.com`. On that page, there is some button or link that takes me to another page that has a URL with a querystring, like `page2.com?value=1&value=2`. What I would like to do is find a way to take the querystring `?value=1&value=2` from the second page and append it to the URL for the first page, when a user clicks their browser's back button.

The goal would be: `page1.com?value=1&value=2`

I am looking for jQuery solutions, only.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! One of the things that will significantly increase the amount of help that users can and will be willing to give you is showing what you have done so far to try and solve the problem yourself before asking us to solve it for you. Add mentions to things that you know, research you have done, or code that you have written to try to solve this issue. Thanks and happy coding! :)

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel okey, Thank you Zach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery Mobiles navigation event as shown below.

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
  var direction = data.state.direction;
  if (direction == 'back') {
    window.location.href = 'your link with parameters';
  }
});
```

Here's a demo.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Q6N6/4/)

Comment: I copied your this method in document.ready function of my page2's  js file but it doesnt even enter the event.. there is something I missing ?

Comment: @user3574311 This event belongs to JQuery Mobile. You need to include JQuery Mobile in your file.

Comment: @user3574311 Check the libraries included in the demo for exact versions of libraries.

Comment: Yes I see now, I am going on check this. Thanks for share Jay

Comment: what if we want this behaviour on non mobile?